# How to avoid writing trailing spaces into text file on redirecting ECHO outputs to a file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this code:

```
@echo off
color 0a
title FTP
CLS
echo username > FTP.txt
echo password >> FTP.txt
ftp -s:FTP.txt ftp.website.com
```

But I have the problem that it shows an error in authentication on execution because a space is appended on `username` and `password` in text file. It other words first line of `FTP.txt`  is "`username` " and not "`username`". Also second line is "`password` " and not "`password`".

How to delete those spaces at end of each line or avoid writing them into the file?

Comment: of course there is a space, if you explicitely write a space. Instead of `echo username > FTP.txt` write `echo username>FTP.txt`. Same with Password.

Comment: If that seems awkward to you, you can also put the redirection at the beginning of the line and achieve the same effect.  `>FTP.txt echo username` and `>>FTP.txt echo password`.  The difference is purely cosmetic.  Or you can `>FTP.txt ( command 1` <enter> `command 2 )`

Answer (score 3):

As Stephan comments above, the space after `username` and `password` is being treated as a literal space, not a token separator.  Remove the spaces before the `>` redirectors.

```js
echo username>FTP.txt
echo password>>FTP.txt
```

If that seems awkward to you, you can also put the redirection at the beginning of the line and achieve the same effect.

```js
>FTP.txt echo username
>>FTP.txt echo password
```

The difference is purely cosmetic.  Or you can open FTP.txt only once for writing, but use multiple statements to write before closing.  This is actually a bit more efficient.

```js
>FTP.txt (
    echo username
    echo password
)
```

or

```js
(
    echo username
    echo password
) >FTP.txt
```