# How to echo a number from 0 to 9 in a Windows batch file to a file without trailing space?

Tags: batch-file, echo, handle, spaces, trailing

If I do the following in a batch file named `test`:

```
echo number=0 > file
```

and run it:

```
> test
> echo number=0  1> file
```

`file` contains:

```
number=0␣
```

If I change `test` to:

```
echo number=1> file
```

and run it:

```
 > test
 > echo number= 1>file
```

`file` contains:

```
number=
```

The `1` apparently is interpreted as `stdout` [handle](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), which is comprehensible.

If I change `test` to:

```
echo number=0> file
```

– and `2` to `9` respectively – and run it:

```
 > test
 > echo number= 0>file
 number=
```

the `0` and `2` to `9` apparently are interpreted as non-`stdout` [handles](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) and `file` is empty, which is comprehensible, too.

With:

```
echo "number=1"> file
```

`file` contains:

```
"number=1"
```

With:

```
echo (number=1)> file
```

`file` contains:

```
(number=1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While writing the question I found the answer at [How to avoid writing trailing spaces into text file on redirecting ECHO outputs to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34210328/1744774):

Put the redirection in front of the command like:

```
> file echo number=0
```

or, as commented by Stephan, [group](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html) the complete command, not just the argument:

```
(echo number=0) > file
```

(The title [*Using parenthesis/brackets to group expressions*](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html) misses a bit, IMHO. It's *to group **commands and** expressions*, isn't it?)

Comment: another possibility: `(echo number=0)>file`